# What's a good rule of thumb for choosing a sufficient number of quantiles in quantile transformation?

Tags: data-transformation, scikit-learn, normalization, quantiles

I'm a currently developing a regression model based on the Choquet Integral. To tackle outliers I am using the Quantile Transformer, provided by scikit-learn. I was wondering how the quantile number corresponds to the quality of the normalized data.

By default, the Quantile Transformer from scikit-learn is setting the number of quantiles to 1000, provided that your data set has more than 1000 instances. But if its below 1000, it sets the quantile number to the number of instances, which intuitively makes me think that the normalized data will have a resolution too high (simply speaking).

So my question is: is there a good rule to determine a sufficient number of quantiles in relation to the size of the data set?

Comment: Please explain what the "Quantile Transformer" does.

Comment: @whuber Quantile transformation estimates the cumulative distribution function of a feature/attribute to provide a quantile normalization and a uniform distribution of values.
First it maps original values to a uniform distribution and then maps obtained values to the desired output distribution using the associated quantile function.

Comment: Thank you -- that's what one might guess.  Applying such a transformation in many cases would amount to an unnecessary step as well as overfitting, so it would be helpful to know more about why you want to do this.